# How to solve Qualcomm Atheros driver problem on ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: wireless

I already install Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and I find out my wireless doesn't work.

Ubuntu cant recognize my wireless on Asus k556uq .

my wireless card is Qualcomm Atheros device 0042 (rev30)

it was output of `lspci` terminal command .

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2; uname -a; rfkill list; dmesg | grep ath` terminal command.

Comment: Last part of question unclear!

Comment: Do you have a connection to the internet by wire on this laptop?

Comment: yes i have wired connection

Answer (score 3):

You need to connect to the internet by wire and update your system by

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
```

It will install the required firmware.

Comment: Doesn't work brow

Comment: Did you reboot?

Comment: yes brow :(((((((((((((((((((

Comment: Did you find a solution, I am facing a similar issue.