# Qualcomm Atheros WiFI, Lenovo v310 & Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, wireless, atheros

Recently purchased Lenovo V310, with Qualcomm Atheros wifi card. The rest of the hardware components work okay, the problem is only with wifi. Issues:

- During installation, when being asked in ubiquity to connect to wifi, I only get an option 'Qualcomm Atheros', instead of wireless networks.
- After Ubuntu is installed and fully updated, wifi doesn't work. There is an option in the wifi dropdown called 'Enable Wireless'. I enable it, but nothing happens. Still no Wifi.

I tried the following solutions:

- [How to solve Qualcomm Atheros driver problem on ubuntu 16.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/859099/how-to-solve-qualcomm-atheros-driver-problem-on-ubuntu-16-04)
- https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2345521
- [Problems with Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 in Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/770897/problems-with-qualcomm-atheros-qca6174-in-ubuntu-16-04)
- [ath10k installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/607707/ath10k-installation) (this one made wifi invisible as if I didn't have a wifi card) and
- [this on Ubuntu Forums](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2348372).

Nothing seems to work. Any idea what I could try next?

As requested, here's the output:

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros Device [168c:0042] (rev 30)
Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:4035]
Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci
Kernel modules: ath10k_pci


0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: yes
2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to disable `ideapad_laptop` module that is blocking the Wi-Fi.

Run in a terminal

```
sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ideapad.conf <<< "blacklist ideapad_laptop"
```

and reboot.

Comment: Why this woudl happen on a fresh install, any explanation(technical) would be great

Comment: The module blocks the wireless device. An explanation would be rather long. It is a kernel issue. Nobody makes quirks for all laptop models.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to disable `ideapad_laptop` anymore; just update the Linux kernel to the latest version (or any version after v4.13). To find out what version you currently have

```
uname -r
```

If you have an older version, you can install a newer one with the Update Manager (e.g. View > Linux kernels). If Update Manager doesn't have v4.13+, you can use the method detailed on [the Ubuntu wiki mainline kernel builds page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/MainlineBuilds). Just get the right deb files from [the Ubuntu kernel page](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.13/), install and reboot.

I had the exact same issue and this fixed it for me.

If you are curious about why this happened, this is what I understood about the problem:

This is a Lenovo V310 issue. The linux kernel comes with `ideapad-laptop.ko` kernel module (you can find it in `/lib/modules/KERNEL-VERSION/kernel/drivers/platform/x86/ideapad-laptop.ko`). This is a generic module for ideapad laptops, and most of them have a hardware switch for wifi. The module will try to read the value of the switch (on/off), and if the switch is absent it will wrongfully interpret it as off, so it disables the wifi. This happens on V310. However, there is a list of laptop models in `ideapad-laptop.ko` that don't have this hardware switch, so the module knows to ignore the value it reads from the switch and just keep wifi on. You can find this list [here in the comment on the patch on GitHub](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/c65da8e22b1d1d8869af69d287fd699c31d2dd58/drivers/platform/x86/ideapad-laptop.c#L960)

Lenovo V310 was not initially on the list, but it was added earlier this year to versions v4.13+ (kinda, if you are really interested about this, check [this commit](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/ccc7179f4d9467947c94f4302d61cd5143842fcd#diff-eab82aebc1bb5f1f275c559c9aec9de1), and [this one](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/710c059c248a24609051f5a3dd1d8468cdc675b0#diff-eab82aebc1bb5f1f275c559c9aec9de1) or look at file history).

So possible solutions would be to update kernel to a version that has V310 (as I described above), add it yourself to `ideapad-laptop.c`, compile the module and replace the one in `lib/modules` or as the previous answer suggested, just disable the entire `ideapad-laptop` module (I guess you miss some functionality here, but it's probably not that big of a deal).